# Spacing comes automatically when i declare any div

Tags: html, css

Any `section / div / header` i declare in `HTML` i am getting `1px`off extra spacing and that causing another issue when I `hover` on any element the other element such as `header` start shaking with animation. I have tried `*{margin:0 padding: 0` but it didn't fix the issue its been 2 days I am trying to figure out but failed maybe you guys can answer

[image: the this is the white spacing I am talking about]

**CSS**

```
       header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
      z-index: 9999;
}
      header .top-bar {
        height: 50px;
        background: #642891;
}
        header .top-bar .logo {
          line-height: 50px;
}
        header .top-bar ul {
          list-style: none;
}
          header .top-bar ul li {
            display: inline-block;
}
            header .top-bar ul li a {
              line-height: 50px;
              padding: 10px;
              color: #fff;
}
            header .top-bar ul li a:hover {
              background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
              border-radius: 4px;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
              transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
      header .navigation {
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
}
        header .navigation ul {
          list-style: none;
          position: relative;
}
          header .navigation ul.menu > li:hover > a {
            background: rgba(100, 40, 145, 0.08);
            color: #642891;
}
          header .navigation ul li {
            display: inline-block;
}
            header .navigation ul li a {
              display: block;
              font-size: 13px;
              font-weight: 500;
              color: #444;
              padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It's important to paste the content of your html file... also, putting `font-size: 0px;` on the css rule `header .top-bar` removes this annoying pixel?

Answer (score 0):

Could you plz post the rendered CSS?
A cause can be that a child element of `.navigation` has a `margin-top` that reaches out the `.navigation` container so you should check those too.

Comment: `.navigation` has no `margin-top` + i am facing this issue only in chrome

Comment: I have posted css please have a look